# Programmatically add toolbar and their contents in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a absolute beginner with a simple question(c# . i want to create a toolbar at runtime and their events . I am using visual studio 2008 , .net framework 3.5 , C# .

Comment: OK So what's stopping you? what you have tried?

Comment: Simply copy the code the designer creates to a runtime event and keep working on it till it workds.

Answer (score 2):

For example, in you form class you can make some like this:

```
ToolStrip toolStrip2 = new ToolStrip();
toolStrip2.Items.Add(new ToolStripDropDownButton());
toolStrip2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
this.Controls.Add(toolStrip2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace DynamicToolStrip
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new DynamicToolStripForm());
        }
        class DynamicToolStripForm : Form
        {
            ToolStrip m_toolstrip = new ToolStrip();
            public DynamicToolStripForm()
            {
                Controls.Add(m_toolstrip);
                AddToolStripButtons();
            }
            void AddToolStripButtons()
            {
                const int iMAX_FILES = 5;
                string[] astrFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");
                for (int i = 0; i < iMAX_FILES; i++)
                {
                    string strFile = astrFiles[i];
                    ToolStripButton tsb = new ToolStripButton();
                    tsb.Text = Path.GetFileName(strFile);
                    tsb.Tag = strFile;
                    tsb.Click += new EventHandler(tsb_Click);
                    m_toolstrip.Items.Add(tsb);
                }
            }
            void tsb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ToolStripButton tsb = sender as ToolStripButton;
                if (tsb != null && tsb.Tag != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hello im the {0} button", tsb.Tag.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```